# Correct hyperlinks in a book with two parts

Tags: hyperref

I am writing a book with two Parts. Each part has six chapters, numbered from 1 to 6. I am using the hyperref package and if I click on the chapter X of the second part, I go the the chapter X of the first part. The problem is solved if the second's part chapters were  numbered from 7, but I do not want to do that.
How can I solve this problem? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. In order to get help it is necessary to post compilable examples, but I think the problem is the resetting of the chapter numbers, which is not the default, actually. Does `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{part.thepart.chapter.\thechapter}` in the preamble help? This will use another anchor for the hyperlinks

Comment: Better use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{...}}` (with ... like in my comment above)

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `hyperref` options according to naming. They may mess up with section numbers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- Did you mean `\thepart`?

Comment: @jon: Oh, yes, of course, `\thepart`. A typo! Thanks

Comment: Any news or can this be closed as 'unclear'?